# post encrypted json to external api in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

excuse me everyone, I'm currently having problems connecting my spring boot application with an open api IoT. to send data to the open api, the request body must be encrypted and sent in json form. I have followed the available documentation, but the response says that the request parameter must be in json format.

here is my program code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.addHeader("x-random-key", randomSecretKey);
httppost.addHeader("x-access-key", xAccessKey);
httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.addHeader("sys_code", "901");
httppost.addHeader("lang", "_en_US");

String encryptedRequestBody = encrypt(request.toString(), randomMessage);
StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(encryptedRequestBody);
strEntity.setContentType("application/json");
httppost.setEntity(strEntity);

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
```